# generate custom python unittest xml report without module errors

Tags: python-3.x, xml, python-unittest

I am trying to run python unittest related tests with command line arguments. I keep getting the modulenotfounderror.

runner

```
sample_test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(Samplepage)
suite_practice = unittest.TestSuite([sample_test])
runner = XMLTestRunner(open('results.xml', 'wb'))
runner.run(suite_practice)
```

test

```
class Samplepage(unittest.TestCase):

def test_Sample(self):
        run_type = sys.argv[1:]
        print("I am in the samplePage, test_sample", run_type[1], run_type[2])
```

The test and runner stay in a different file. If I change the implementation in the runner, the test runs twice. I should only run the test once with XML report.

To run the test

```
python -m unittest testfile.py 1 2
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception. Also: " If I change the implementation in the runner, the test runs twice" - how did you change the implementation? Did the error go away in that case?

Comment: @MrBean Bremen Here is the link to it https://github.com/psuryateja123/stackoverflow/blob/master/sample

Comment: First - please put the needed information in th _question_, not somewhere else. Second: It is unclear what your actual question is - is it about passing command line arguments to unittest? Or do you want to achieve something this way that can be done in another way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, I am trying to get an XML report, without running the tests twice and without module errors in the xml report. Please do let me know.